# Are these outer measures?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Are the following outer measures?

(i) $\mu^*(A)=0$ if $A \subseteq X$ countable and $\mu^*(A)=1$ otherwise.

(ii) $\mu^*(A)=0$ if $\{x,y\} \cap A = \emptyset$ and $\mu^*(A)=1$ otherwise.

(iii) $\mu^*(A)=0$ is $\{x,y\} \cap A^C \neq \emptyset$ and $\mu^*(A)=1$ otherwise.

I would say yes they are, I tried to check all three properties, so that the emptyset has measure $0$, the monotonicity and the $\sigma$-subadditivity.

If they are, I now have to determine the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}(\mu^*)=\{A \subseteq X: A \text{ is } \mu^* \text{ measurable }\}$ where a set $A$ is $\mu^*$ measurable, if $\mu^*(Q)=\mu^*(Q \cap A) + \mu^*(Q \cap A^C) \forall Q \subseteq X$. Can someone tell me, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

It is enough to check the inequality $\mu^{*}\left(Q\right)\geq\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A\right)+\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A^{c}\right)$. The $\leq$-side is a consequence of the fact that $\mu^{*}$ is an outer measure.

Also $\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A\right)\leq\mu^{*}\left(Q\right)$
and $\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A^{c}\right)\leq\mu^{*}\left(Q\right)$ as consequence of the fact that $\mu^{*}$ is an outer measure.

Here $\mu^{*}\left(B\right)\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ for each $B$.

So when do we **not** have $\mu^{*}\left(Q\right)\geq\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A\right)+\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A^{c}\right)$ for each set $Q$?

If and only if some $Q$ exists with $\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A\right)=\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A^{c}\right)=1$.

---

**edit**:

Let's have a look at case (ii) where $\mu^{*}$ is indeed an outer measure.

If $x\in A$ and $y\in A^{c}$
or - switching their roles - if $y\in A$ and $x\in A^{c}$ then
for set $Q=\left\{ x,y\right\} $ we find $\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A\right)=\mu^{*}\left(Q\cap A^{c}\right)=1$.

Our conclusion is that $A$ is **not** measurable.

If on the other hand
$x,y\in A$ or $x,y\in A^{c}$ then such a set cannot be found.

Conclusion:
$\mathcal{A}\left(\mu^{*}\right)=\left\{ A\in\wp\left(X\right)\mid x,y\in A\vee x,y\in A^{c}\right\} $.

Comment: So for the second one, is it true that I only get the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, X\}$, because if I take $Q=\{x,y\}$ and pick $x \in A$ and $y \in A^C$, then $\mu^*(Q \cap A)=\mu^*(Q \cap A^C)=1$...?

Comment: No. See my edit.

Comment: Okay I See, and in the First Case? Do I get $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: You get all the sets that are countable together with all the sets that are cocountable (i.e. their complement is countable). If set $A$ does not belong to this class of sets  then $A$ and $A^c$ are both not countable and $Q=X$ is a set with $\mu^*(Q\cap A)=\mu^*(Q\cap A^c)=1$

Comment: For the third case, I again tried to take the set $Q=\{x,y\}$ but it seems then for all three cases, so $x,y\in A, x \in A$ and $y \in A^C, x,y \in A^C$ that $A$ is measurable. So what does that mean? Could you give me a hint? Is there a $Q$ such that $A$ is not measurable?

Comment: And another question to (i): If we have $A$ some not countable set, why is $\mu^*(Q \cap A)=1$? What if $A$ is some uncountable set containing $X$, then the intersection would be $X$ and the outer measure would be because of its definiton $0$ or not? What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: on your last comment: I took $Q=X$ there, so that $Q\cap A=X\cap A=A$ and consequently $\mu^*(Q\cap A)=\mu^*(A)=1$ if $A$ is not countable. There is only one set $A$ that contains $X$ wich is $A=X$ itself. Based on what do you draw the conclusion that by definition its outer measure takes value $0$? If $A=X$ is uncountable then by definition its outer measure takes value $1$.

Comment: Case (iii) is tricky: $\mu^*$ is **not** an outer measure here (have you checked that?). Note that $\mu^*(\{x\})=\mu^*(\{y\})=0$ and $\mu^*(\{x,y\})=1$.